# Example of `set value` in material-ui Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm having a hard time to set a default value in the `DatePicker` component of `material-ui`.

From the docs:

`value   object      Sets the date for the Date Picker programmatically.`

source: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/date-picker

But this is a really bad description, it says a object but it doesn't say what properties, or the structure. 
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

EDIT: I've tried filling the `value` prop with `new Date(dateVariable)` but it's showing the date of one day before, which makes me think about timezone( here is -03 GMT ). So I'd like to know if the correct way of filling this prop, and different paths that I can take. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. The same for the `minDate` and `maxDate` props.